# Oracle SQL: how to pass parameter to a function that is used in a view through a column in a view?

Tags: sql, oracle, function, view

Let's say we have such view that uses function with hard-coded parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW x AS
SELECT t.some_value
  FROM table(function(p1 => '1')) t;
```

If I'd like to pass that parameter to a function through a view, what are possible options? Please mind that using global or context/bind variables is not an option. So far I've came up with an option to use a table that holds all available parameter values (keys) that could be passed to a view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW x AS
SELECT st.input_param,
       t.some_value
  FROM some_table st
       table(function(p1 => st.input_param)) t;
```

However, I am wondering if there are any other possible options?

Comment: You cannot pass a bind parameter  in a view, at least not until version 20c, where the sql macro facility allows something like this.

Comment: I think your choice is the best way. I have views like that where they retrieve dynamic parameters from a parameter table. a single process stores the effective date in a settings table, and all the views are configured to use the function to retrieve which effective date is the one for the filter.

Comment: If you can use a table to hold value, then how come "context is not an option".  That doeesnt make sense, because if you have a table, then you could have a trigger on that table to populate a context no?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a parameter to a view but you can use the next alternative:

```
CREATE TYPE RECORDS_VARCHAR AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);

create or replace function virtual_table( input_param number )
return RECORDS_VARCHAR
PIPELINED
is

begin
FOR a IN (
            select '1' AS VALUE from dual where input_param = 2
            UNION ALL
            select '8' AS VALUE from dual
          ) loop
pipe row (a.VALUE);
end loop;
return;
end;


SELECT * FROM TABLE(virtual_table(2)); --1,8

SELECT * FROM TABLE(virtual_table(1)); --8
```